# How to install a shared library to a non standard path in Android?

Tags: android

I have a userspace driver that gets picked up by a daemon. The daemon looks for userspace drivers in a specific directory (system/foobar/drivers). How can i tell Android.mk to install the shared library into system/foobar/drivers instead of system/lib.

Comment: +1 for nice question. but i dont think that its possible to assign system/foobar/drivers as output folder. so either you have to copy manually, this shared lib. to above mentioned location or change the path where daemon is looking for to system/lib.

Answer (score 0):

This has no clean solution . You can try setting LD_Library_Path but it gets overlooked. A twisted solution http://www.koushikdutta.com/2009/05/androids-linker-makes-baby-jesus-cry.html